# Weak Convergence Lemma - Is Banach needed?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

**Lemma.** Let $X$ be a normed space.

- If $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ in $X$ and $x_n^* \to x^*$ in $X^*$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n^*(x_n) = x^*(x)$.
- If $X$ is even Banach, then $x_n \to x$ in $X$ and $x_n^* \overset{*}\rightharpoonup x^*$ in $X^*$ implies $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n^*(x_n) = x^*(x)$.

The lecture notes I work with, had this wrong at first - it didn't include Banach for the second statement. (The proof uses boundedness of $(x_n^*)$ which relies on Banach-Steinhaus!)

Is Banach really needed, though? Does anyone have a counterexample?

Comment: what do you mean by $x_n ^*$?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to type it out, it‘s supposed to be some element from the dual space. (The lemma deals with weak convergence and weak-$*$-convergence.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a counter-example for the second statement without $X$ being complete. The first statement is valid for non-complete $X$ (by means of embedding into the Banach space $X^{**}$).

Take $X=c_{00}$ provided with the $l^2$-norm. Define $x_n = n^{-1}e_n$ and
$$
x_n^*(y):= n y_n.
$$ 
Then $x_n^*\rightharpoonup^*0$, $x_n\to0$, but $x_n^*(x_n)=1 $ for all $n$.

Comment: Nice one :) (And yes, the first statement is valid for non-complete spaces, as you said. Now that I think about it, Banach-Steinhaus is used for $X^*$ here, so completeness is sort of intrinsic due to the dual space.)